# How to prove that the boolean inequality of a type with itself is uninhabited in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I was wondering how to prove that `(So (not (y == y)))` is an instance of `Uninhabited`, and I'm not sure how to go about it. Is it provable in Idris, or is not provable due to the possibility of a weird `Eq` implementation for y?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213584/in-idris-can-i-prove-free-theorems-e-g-the-only-total-function-of-type-for I would say you can't prove such things. At least in general because you don't now implementation of `(==)` for every type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Eq` interface does not require an implementation to follow the normal laws of equality. But, we can define an extended `LawfulEq` interface which does:

```
%default total

is_reflexive : (t -> t -> Bool) -> Type
is_reflexive {t} rel = (x : t) -> rel x x = True

is_symmetric : (t -> t -> Bool) -> Type
is_symmetric {t} rel = (x : t) -> (y : t) -> rel x y = rel y x

is_transitive : (t -> t -> Bool) -> Type
is_transitive {t} rel = (x : t) -> (y : t) -> (z : t) -> rel x y = True -> rel x z = rel y z

interface Eq t => LawfulEq t where
  eq_is_reflexive : is_reflexive {t} (==)
  eq_is_symmetric : is_symmetric {t} (==)
  eq_is_transitive : is_transitive {t} (==)
```

The result asked for in the question can be proved for type `Bool`:

```
so_false_is_void : So False -> Void
so_false_is_void Oh impossible

so_not_y_eq_y_is_void : (y : Bool) -> So (not (y == y)) -> Void
so_not_y_eq_y_is_void False = so_false_is_void
so_not_y_eq_y_is_void True = so_false_is_void
```

The result can be proved not true for the following `Weird` type:

```
data Weird = W

Eq Weird where
  W == W = False

weird_so_not_y_eq_y : (y : Weird) -> So (not (y == y))
weird_so_not_y_eq_y W = Oh
```

The `Weird (==)` can be shown to be not reflexive, so an implementation of `LawfulEq Weird` is not possible:

```
weird_eq_not_reflexive : is_reflexive {t=Weird} (==) -> Void
weird_eq_not_reflexive is_reflexive_eq = 
  let w_eq_w_is_true = is_reflexive_eq W in
    trueNotFalse $ trans (sym w_eq_w_is_true) (the (W == W = False) Refl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shersh is right: you can't.  Implementations of `(==)` aren't guaranteed to be reflexive, so it might not be true.

You could restrict the type of `y` so that you are proving a property of a specific implementation of `(==)`, but I suspect you want to use `decEq` and `(=)` instead of `So` and `(==)`.  It's easy to show `Not (y = y)` is uninhabited.